# SQL how to use IN while using ISNULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following param below would look something like (2,3,4,5) or (2) or even be NULL the column ServiceEntryPart could have data as below in the code section. My question is what will be the correct syntax so I could use the filter. If the filter is NULL, I will totally ignore it. What I have so far works fine if its a NULL (Excludes the filter) but when I have the param for example (1,2), it does not work.. Thanks

```
ServiceEntryPart.ServiceTypeIDs 
 4,3
 3
 NULL
 1
 8
 2,5

--Filter:
  @ServiceTypes nvarchar(100) = NULL

--Filter with values SET @ServiceTypes = (1,2,4,5)      

--Where Clause  
WHERE   (ServiceEntryPart.ServiceTypeIDs = ISNULL(@ServiceTypes,ServiceEntryPart.ServiceTypeIDs)
```

Comment: You cannot pass an entire `IN` list to a query as a single named parameter, with or without `ISNULL`.

Comment: so what is the solution you are saying?

Comment: You need to define the behavior that you want. If the parameter is @ServiceTypes is null do you want to a) ignore the parameter or b) only pick up null values? Also breaking 1NF is bad idea.

Comment: @Conrad I would like to use this filter if it includes a value, if its null then I totally ignore it.

Comment: Getting a negative on a question is a hint that your question needs a fix. Closing votes indicate that your question is too cryptic to be fixed.

Comment: @user1475788 ok so those numbers above ServiceTypes. Does that represent possible inputs? Values of ServiceTypeIDs? both?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You **can** pass a table parameter to a stored procedure in SQL 2008 +

Comment: @CONRAD, I edited the question, Its more descriptive

Comment: @podiluska Ah, right, I forgot about table parameters. They aren't trivial, though, and you need to define a user type on the server side to use them (the reason I stick with temp tables).

Comment: @user1475788 well then NULL is the least of your problems. You'll need to write (or find) a split function and then split both your the values in your columns and your input parameter. look at [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+code%3A%22dbo.Split%22&submit=search) or [this SQL Forum](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648). Welcome to the joys of breaking 1st normal form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to pass in a variable list for an IN clause.  One way is with dynamic SQL, but I would say that is overkill.

You can try something like:

```
where @ServiceTypes is null or
      charindex(','+cast(ServiceEntryPart.ServiceTypeIDs as varchar(255)+',',
                ','+@ServiceTypes+',') > 0
```

This is using a string search to do the equivalent of IN.  It assumes that @ServiceTypes is a comma delimited list with no spaces.  It prepends and postpends a comma.  When you look for something like 5, it really looks for ",5," so it does not match 25 or 55 in the list.

Comment: I see, this is great!  Appreciate your answer!! :)